# How to build conda recipes based on arguments passed with the `conda build` command

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I would like to have a single recipe to build all my individual python packages in my repository. (There are multiple ones here.) This is how the repo is structured:

```
repo
|--package1
   |--setup.py
|--package2
   |--setup.py
|--package3
   |--setup.py
|--recipe
   |--meta.yaml
```

I would like to build each package in the following manner:

```
conda build recipe/ --variants "{'package':['package1','package2','package3']}"
```

This should allow me to pickup the package and set the path accordingly in the meta.yaml file:

```
source:
  path: ../{{ package }}
```

1. Is is possible to access the variants data from within the recipe?
2. If not, are there alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: There IS a way to achieve this, using recipe variants and "selectors" in `meta.yaml`.  But I don't recommend it.  A more standard scheme is to simply maintain a separate recipe for each package, located within the package's own source code.  For example, `repo/package1/conda-recipe`, `repo/package2/conda-recipe`, etc.  Then you can build them all at once via `conda build package1/conda-recipe package2/conda-recipe ...`.

Comment: The reason your scheme is not recommended is that usually different packages will have significantly different recipes.  For example, their version numbers and build requirements will usually differ.  Same for everything in the `about` section of `meta.yaml`.  In theory, it would be possible to make ALL of the fields in `meta.yaml` selectively enabled/disabled using "selectors" and/or jinja templates, but the result will be needlessly complex.  It's simpler to maintain a separate recipe for each package.  Ideally, you should store the recipe directory within the package's own source code.